# ClientValidationFunction for CustomValidator fails while setting args.IsValid true/false

Tags: javascript, asp.net, customvalidator

I have a CustomValidator with ClientValidationFunction as below

```
function checkAmount(source, args) {
        var opt = document.getElementById('<%=optByAmount.ClientID %>');
        var txt = document.getElementById('<%=txtAmount.ClientID %>');
        if (opt.checked == true && txt.value == '') {
            //args.IsValid = false;
            alert('failed');
        }
        else {
            //args.IsValid = true;
            alert('passed');
        }
    }
```

I receive error messages 'passed' and 'failed' ONLY when the commented lines are COMMENTED. When these lines are enabled, i don't get any alert at all. Why ??

**EDIT**
After stopping and running the code for 20 minutes (doing something other than this part of the code), It is working now !!! Thanks Damian and ub1k. I would never know why was it happening :(

Answer (score 1):

Could you please add additional line to your code?

```
alert(args);
```

in the first line?

I have double checked your code and it works perfectly for me. Apart from that I used CustomValidator many times and the problem is probably somewhere else. For now if you could check whether args exist it would be helpful.

Comment: it says "undefined" Here is the CustomValidator, I might have been calling this incorrectly     <asp:CustomValidator runat="server" id="txtAmount_CustomValidator" ClientValidationFunction="checkAmount"
ErrorMessage="Please enter Amount" ValidationGroup="abc" 
ControlToValidate="txtAmount" >*</asp:CustomValidator>

Comment: Please check source argument as well. And if it is not null also check source.IsValid.
Did you alter default validation mechanism in your project?
I would suggest you to check it out on the clean project to make sure that it works outside of your destination solution.

Comment: After stopping and running the code for 20 minutes (doing something other than this part of the code), It is working now !!!

Answer (score 0):

Most probably because the

```
args.IsValid = true/false;
```

throws an exception and the code execution doesn't follow from then on

shouldn't args be initialized as an array somehow?

Comment: I was expecting an exception too but why?. I found various examples as args.IsValid = true/false; with no init. The question is why is it failing? Probably somehow args does not have IsValid but why and how ?

Comment: agreed. the cause is most probably somewhere else. there's nothing more constructive that I can say then that you'd have to study the other examples that you have that work and look for differences. Sometimes those slight differences that seem not important actually cause the behaviour changes.